# Extract conditional values from data.frame into a vector in one line in R

Tags: r, vector, row, subset, multiple-columns

This is a very basic question, but I cannot find how to do it.

How can I extract specific values from a `data.frame` into a vector in one line?
For example, using `mtcars` dataset, how can I extract the disp values from when `cyl==6` into a vector, please, so that:

```
 cyl6.disp <- c(160.0, 160.0, 258.0, 225.0, 167.6, 167.6, 145.0)
```

Comment: You can use `cyl6.disp <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6,]$disp` (base R) or `cyl6.disp <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 6) %>% pull(disp)` (dplyr package) @Sylvia Rodriguez

Comment: Perfect! ¡Gracias! :)